# How to create an infinite scrolling loop with Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I'm new to apple developing and have a question about Core Animation, which from what I understand allows you to create animations with objects / Images.

There are multiple tutorials out there but they all simply show the code and not really explain how it works. Because of this when trying to use Core Animation in my app I have had some difficulty.

My aim is to create the illusion of a never ending image using a tillable image. I have an understanding of the basic concept, I have 2 UIImageViews set up and originally i tried setting them up using an NSTimer calling 2 methods every 0.01 seconds. One moving the object by simply adding 1 to the Y value each time it is called and another checking the position of each UIImageView each time it is called, then when it reached the pixel that allowed it to be completely off the bottom of the screen it reset it to the top, unfortunately it was very laggy and the reset never worked properly.

Now ive turned to Core Animation since i get the impression that that was the intended way to create moving objects. I have used my minimal knowledge of it to create some animations but nothing I tried really worked.

Hopefully someone can help me create the illusion of an infinite image with two UIImageViews. I don't mind if you explain how to make one with Core Animation or if you want to fix the idea of the original code I wrote.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample `UIViewController` I whipped up. It uses basic `UIView` instances instead of `UIImageView`, but those should be direct-swap items.

In my testing, the effect is the appearance of a never-ending banner of red and blue (i.e., the view controller's white background is never seen).

This does **NOT** use `CAAnimation`, but rather utilizes blocks-based animations provided for `UIView`, which I think is a lot easier to manage.

Does this give you what you want?

**Note: this neglects to include the header file `ViewController.h`, but it is completely empty of any code.**

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

// Private Interface
@interface ViewController ()

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Controls
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *view1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *view2;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Private Properties
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isVisible;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *view1HeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *view2HeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *view1TopConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *view2TopConstraint;
@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupUserInterface];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // At this point, self.view has its correct size,
    // so use it to set the height of the sub views
    self.view1HeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
    self.view2HeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // The screen has been shown, so store this value and begin the animations
    self.isVisible  = YES;
    [self slideDown1];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    // So that the animations will stop and this view controller can be released
    self.isVisible  = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Animations
- (void)slideDown1 {
    // This sets the top of view1's frame equal to the bottom of self.view.frame
    self.view1TopConstraint.constant    = self.view.frame.size.height;
    // This sets the top of view2's frame equal to the top of self.view.frame
    self.view2TopConstraint.constant    = 0.0f;

    // If we didn't call this block, the changes set above would take effect "immediately"
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
                         // Calling this inside of an animation causes the changes above to be animated
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // This block will execute when the animations finish

                         // This moves self.view1 so that its bottom is aligned with the top of self.view
                         self.view1TopConstraint.constant   = -1.0f * self.view.frame.size.height;

                         // This causes the line above to take place immediately
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                         if (self.isVisible == YES) {
                             // If the screen is still visible, start the next animation
                             [self slideDown2];
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
- (void)slideDown2 {
    self.view1TopConstraint.constant    = 0.0f;
    self.view2TopConstraint.constant    = self.view.frame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.view2TopConstraint.constant   = -1.0f * self.view.frame.size.height;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         if (self.isVisible == YES) {
                             [self slideDown1];
                         }
                     }
     ];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Setup
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createControls];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
}
- (void)createControls {
    self.view1  = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view2  = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
- (void)setupControls {
    self.view1.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];
    // This line is required for our "full auto layout",
    // which just means (in this case) that we're doing it all in code
    [self.view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    self.view2.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

}
- (void)layoutControls {
    // The subviews have to be added to self.view before we can constrain them
    [self.view addSubview:self.view1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.view2];

    // This sets up the subviews to make their width equal to self.view's width
    // You could have also used this method for the views' heights
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:0.0f]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:0.0f]];

    // This gives us properties we can use later to animate the views' movements
    self.view1TopConstraint     = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view1
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0.0f];
    // You created the constraint, but it has to be installed/added
    [self.view addConstraint:self.view1TopConstraint];

    // A different and probably less effective way to set the heights of the subviews
    self.view1HeightConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view1
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:nil
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.view1HeightConstraint];

    self.view2TopConstraint     = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.view2TopConstraint];

    self.view2HeightConstraint  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:nil
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                              multiplier:1.0f
                                                                constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.view2HeightConstraint];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks man, i haven't tried out the code yet but it looks like it should do what i want. Could you possibly add a few comments to the code since at some point I will need to change the code slightly to fit with the game I'm trying to design and because of my basic knowledge of objective-c I don't fully understand what each part does, especially with constraints (I already have constraints set up from the Main storyboard) and also all the properties you set. if you could that would be great if not thats fine :) Thanks